# Rebuilding reduce and each

Tags: javascript

Recently had an interview for a programming related gig. The interviewer made me rewrite **each** first, this I had no problem with and understood completely. Heres my each method:

```
var each = function(arrayItems,callback){
  //if arrayItems is not an array
  if(!Array.isArray(arrayItems)){
    //write a for in loop to iterate through the object
    for(var key in arrayItems){
      //store the value, the key and the whole object as the callback parameters 
      callback(arrayItems[key],key,arrayItems);
    }
  }
  //if arrayItems wasn't an object iterate through the array
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayItems.length; i++){
    //store the value,key and whole array as the callback's parameters
    callback(arrayItems[i],i,arrayItems);  
  }
};
```

Second he had my rewrite **reduce** this no matter how many times I research devdocs and pick apart every piece of code I have trouble understanding here's my method:

```
var reduce = function(array,callback,initialValue){
      // Implementing each into reduce
      each(array,function(number){
      //This is the line of code that confuses me
      initialValue = callback(initialValue,number);
      });
    };
```

I'm looking for somebody to elaborate on the second line of code in reduce. How does this work initialValue is a function with initialValue and number as the parameters. Do initialValue and number need to be in a certain order? How does it work that initial value is equal to a function with intialValue and number as the callback? Also how does it know to execute the code if its something like : `[number(s)].reduce(function(a,b){return a + b;},intialValue)` I know these questions may seem a little vague, the interview is long gone but as a personal challenge I want to understand what is going on better.

Comment: Erm... so you're confused by something as trivial as `x = foo(x,y)`?

Comment: @nietthedarkabsol Yes, please.. elaborate

Answer (score 1):

> *"How does this work `initialValue` is a function with `initialValue` and `number` as the parameters.*"

I assume you mean *`callback`* is a function. If so, yes, it will be passed arguments, but more than just two.

The first is what you have as `initialValue`, though this adds confusion, because after the first time you update it, it's no longer the initial value. Better to use a different variable name.

The second is the current item in the iteration. You have it a name `number`, but it may not be a number. Again a confusing name.

The third should be the index of the current iteration.

The fourth should be the original collection.

---

> *"Do `initialValue` and `number` need to be in a certain order?"*

Of course. That's the "accumulator" of your final value and the value of the current iteration. The user needs to know which is which.

---

> *"How does it work that initial value is equal to a function with `intialValue` and `number` as the callback?"*

Every iteration, the callback is supposed to return the updated value of the accumulator. That value gets passed as the first argument of the next iteration.

---

> *"Also how does it know to execute the code if its something like : `[number(s)].reduce(function(a,b){return a + b;},intialValue)`"*

That's an odd example, but if you had a correct Array, and you passed something like `0`, then `a` is the accumulator, which will be equal to either the `initialValue` that you passed, or the return value of the previous iteration.

---

A more reasonable example of the use of `.reduce()` would be:

```
var result = [2,4,3,8,6].reduce(function(acc, curr, i, arr) {
    console.log(acc, curr);
    return acc + curr;
}, 0);
```

So on the first iteration, `acc` *(short for accumulator)* will be `0` *(the initial value given)*, and `curr` *(short for current)* will be the number `2`, which is the first item in the Array.

The return value is then `0 + 2`.

On the second iteration, `acc` is the value of the last return, which was `0 + 2` or `2`, and `curr` is the second item in the Array, which is `4`.

The return value is then `2 + 4`.

On the third iteration, `acc` is the value of the last return, which was `2 + 4` or `6`, and `curr` is the third item in the Array, which is `3`.

The return value is then `6 + 3`.

...and so on.

So as you can see, it's just taking either the intial value, or the return value of the previous iteration, passing it as the first argument, letting you do whatever manipulation you want, and then taking your return value and passing it as the first argument of the next iteration.

This continues until the loop is complete, at which point `.reduce()` gives you whatever you returned from the last iteration.

---

Note that neither of your functions are ECMAScript compliant. The first one operates on plain objects??? And both are missing certain details.

Comment: `The first one operates on plain objects?` yes, it should as *forEach* `…is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object` ([ECMA-262 §5.4.4.18](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18)). In regard to `…both are missing certain details`—yes, quite a few. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: Certainly you don't think it's intended to operate in the manner which was coded in the rewrite. Yes, they're generic. Doesn't mean that it's a general purpose property enumerator. That's what I was referring to by "plain objects".

Comment: —yes, some of the missing details are checking that visited properties are valid idexes and for own properties befor acting. At least it only visits properties that exist. :-)

Comment: @RobG: If we're talking about the ECMAScript implementation of `.forEach()`, it wouldn't technically be a check that the property is a valid index, though the properties it would try to get would be valid indices. But they don't need to be "own" properties. They can be inherited. They do of course need to exist. Certainly though it wouldn't be anything like a `for-in` as OP coded.

Comment: You're right, [*forEach*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) may visit inherited properties. It will only visit valid indexes (since it only checks from 0 to length), so the loop should be like `for (var i=0, iLen=obj.length; i<iLen; i++) { if (i in obj) {...}}` so only valid indexes that exist and are in range at the start are visited.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the underscore core functions!

```
if (typeof (/./) !== 'function') {
    _.isFunction = function(obj) {
      return typeof obj === 'function';
    };
  }
_.bind = function(func, context) {
    var args, bound;
    if (nativeBind && func.bind === nativeBind) return nativeBind.apply(func, slice.call(arguments, 1));
    if (!_.isFunction(func)) throw new TypeError;
    args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return bound = function() {
      if (!(this instanceof bound)) return func.apply(context, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
      ctor.prototype = func.prototype;
      var self = new ctor;
      ctor.prototype = null;
      var result = func.apply(self, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
      if (Object(result) === result) return result;
      return self;
    };
  };

_.has = function(obj, key) {
    return hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
  };

_.keys = function(obj) {
    if (!_.isObject(obj)) return [];
    if (nativeKeys) return nativeKeys(obj);
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) if (_.has(obj, key)) keys.push(key);
    return keys;
  };

_.each = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj == null) return obj;
    if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
      obj.forEach(iterator, context);
    } else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
      for (var i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    } else {
      var keys = _.keys(obj);
      for (var i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (iterator.call(context, obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    }
    return obj;
  };


 _.reduce = function(obj, iterator, memo, context) {
    var initial = arguments.length > 2;
    if (obj == null) obj = [];
    if (nativeReduce && obj.reduce === nativeReduce) {
      if (context) iterator = _.bind(iterator, context);
      return initial ? obj.reduce(iterator, memo) : obj.reduce(iterator);
    }
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      if (!initial) {
        memo = value;
        initial = true;
      } else {
        memo = iterator.call(context, memo, value, index, list);
      }
    });
    if (!initial) throw new TypeError(reduceError);
    return memo;
  };
```

Comment: `underscore` will use the `native` functions if they exist, if not then it chooses to use it's own implementations that do not follow the ECMA5 specifications for it's `fallbacks`. They choose not to follow them because of known bugs in older browsers, especially IE<9 and it's broken `Array` implementation. So they treat arrays as `dense`. I don't really think this code helps with understanding.

Comment: A better example would be to show the code that is being used in [`es5_shim`](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) or [polyfill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill)s as given by MDN for [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on if you want `forEach` and `reduce` to be similar (simple but not to spec) or as close as possible/reasonable to the ECMA5 spec. To best understand them, I would suggest reading the specifications.

> [Array.prototype.forEach ( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18)
>
> callbackfn should be a function that accepts three arguments. forEach calls callbackfn once for each element present in the array, in ascending order. callbackfn is called only for elements of the array which actually exist; it is not called for missing elements of the array.
>
> If a thisArg parameter is provided, it will be used as the this value for each invocation of callbackfn. If it is not provided, undefined is used instead.
>
> callbackfn is called with three arguments: the value of the element, the index of the element, and the object being traversed.
>
> forEach does not directly mutate the object on which it is called but the object may be mutated by the calls to callbackfn.
>
> The range of elements processed by forEach is set before the first call to callbackfn. Elements which are appended to the array after the call to forEach begins will not be visited by callbackfn. If existing elements of the array are changed, their value as passed to callback will be the value at the time forEach visits them; elements that are deleted after the call to forEach begins and before being visited are not visited.
>
> When the forEach method is called with one or two arguments, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.
> 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with the argument "length".
> 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
> 4. If IsCallable(callbackfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
> 6. Let k be 0.
> 7. Repeat, while k < len
> 8. Let Pk be ToString(k).
> 9. Let kPresent be the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of O with argument Pk.
> 10. If kPresent is true, then
> 11. Let kValue be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with argument Pk.
> 12. Call the [[Call]] internal method of callbackfn with T as the this value and argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
> 13. Increase k by 1.
> 14. Return undefined.
>
> The length property of the forEach method is 1.
>
> NOTE The forEach function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the forEach function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.

-

> [Array.prototype.reduce ( callbackfn [ , initialValue ] )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21)
>
> callbackfn should be a function that takes four arguments. reduce calls the callback, as a function, once for each element present in the array, in ascending order.
>
> callbackfn is called with four arguments: the previousValue (or value from the previous call to callbackfn), the currentValue (value of the current element), the currentIndex, and the object being traversed. The first time that callback is called, the previousValue and currentValue can be one of two values. If an initialValue was provided in the call to reduce, then previousValue will be equal to initialValue and currentValue will be equal to the first value in the array. If no initialValue was provided, then previousValue will be equal to the first value in the array and currentValue will be equal to the second. It is a TypeError if the array contains no elements and initialValue is not provided.
>
> reduce does not directly mutate the object on which it is called but the object may be mutated by the calls to callbackfn.
>
> The range of elements processed by reduce is set before the first call to callbackfn. Elements that are appended to the array after the call to reduce begins will not be visited by callbackfn. If existing elements of the array are changed, their value as passed to callbackfn will be the value at the time reduce visits them; elements that are deleted after the call to reduce begins and before being visited are not visited.
>
> When the reduce method is called with one or two arguments, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.
> 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with the argument "length".
> 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
> 4. If IsCallable(callbackfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> 5. If len is 0 and initialValue is not present, throw a TypeError exception.
> 6. Let k be 0.
> 7. If initialValue is present, then
> 8. Set accumulator to initialValue.
> 9. Else, initialValue is not present
> 10. Let kPresent be false.
> 11. Repeat, while kPresent is false and k < len
> 12. Let Pk be ToString(k).
> 13. Let kPresent be the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of O with argument Pk.
> 14. If kPresent is true, then
> 15. Let accumulator be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with argument Pk.
> 16. Increase k by 1.
> 17. If kPresent is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> 18. Repeat, while k < len
> 19. Let Pk be ToString(k).
> 20. Let kPresent be the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of O with argument Pk.
> 21. If kPresent is true, then
> 22. Let kValue be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with argument Pk.
> 23. Let accumulator be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of callbackfn with undefined as the this value and argument list containing accumulator, kValue, k, and O.
> 24. Increase k by 1.
> 25. Return accumulator.
>
> The length property of the reduce method is 1.
>
> NOTE The reduce function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the reduce function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.

Which for me I would write (and these are not 100% to spec, but close). You could of course write them exactly as described in the specs above.

**Helper functions**

```
function firstToCapital(inputString) {
    return inputString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputString.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

function isClass(inputArg, className) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(inputArg) === '[object ' + firstToCapital(className) + ']';
}

function throwIfNotAFunction(inputArg) {
    if (!isClass(inputArg, 'function')) {
        throw TypeError('Argument is not a function');
    }

    return inputArg;
}
```

**Abstracts described in the speciications**

```
function checkObjectCoercible(inputArg) {
    if (typeof inputArg === 'undefined' || inputArg === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert argument to object');
    }

    return inputArg;
};

function ToObject(inputArg) {
    checkObjectCoercible(inputArg);
    if (isClass(inputArg, 'boolean')) {
        inputArg = new Boolean(inputArg);
    } else if (isClass(inputArg, 'number')) {
        inputArg = new Number(inputArg);
    } else if (isClass(inputArg, 'string')) {
        inputArg = new String(inputArg);
    }

    return inputArg;
}

function ToUint32(inputArg) {
    return inputArg >>> 0;
}
```

**forEach**

```
function forEach(array, fn, thisArg) {
    var object = ToObject(array),
        length,
        index;

    throwIfNotAFunction(fn);
    length = ToUint32(object.length);
    for (index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
        if (index in object) {
            fn.call(thisArg, object[index], index, object);
        }
    }
}
```

**reduce**

```
function reduce(array, fn, initialValue) {
    var object = ToObject(array),
        accumulator,
        length,
        kPresent,
        index;

    throwIfNotAFunction(fn);
    length = ToUint32(object.length);
    if (!length && arguments.length === 2) {
        throw new TypeError('reduce of empty array with no initial value');
    }

    index = 0;
    if (arguments.length > 2) {
        accumulator = initialValue;
    } else {
        kPresent = false;
        while (!kPresent && index < length) {
            kPresent = index in object;
            if (kPresent) {
                accumulator = object[index];
                index += 1;
            }
        }

        if (!kPresent) {
            throw new TypeError('reduce of empty array with no initial value');
        }
    }

    while (index < length) {
        if (index in object) {
            accumulator = fn.call(undefined, accumulator, object[index], index, object);
        }

        index += 1;
    }

    return accumulator;
}
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/mU8QY/)